# how to create binary tree in pep8 OR see the assembly code of java code

Tags: java, assembly, tree, binary-tree, pep8-assembly

Hello i have a question and i hope to find some answers

i want to create a binary tree in pep8  to  make some prefix arithmetic

so   to do 2+3  the  user  have  to enter   + 3 2
to  do  (3*2)-3          the  user  have to enter   - * 3 2 3

i did  it in  java and  it's  :

```
  class BinaryTree {

    public char opt;//  = {*,+,/,-}
    public int val; 
public char variable ='\0'; 
public boolean feuille = true;
public BinaryTree left;
public BinaryTree right;

  }
```

other  question :  i have done all the code in java  , can i see the assembly code of my java programm?   so  after that i will create a pep8 programm using the assembly code

Comment: pep8 seems to be a coding style guide for python, but you're asking about assembly, did you mean pdp 8?

Comment: Java is typically compiled into _bytecode_. At runtime, the Java Virtual Machine can interpret the bytecode, or translate it into machine code for your target machine using Just In Time compilation.

Comment: @harold ........https://code.google.com/p/pep8-1/   ......it's : Pep/8 Assembler and Simulator ...

Comment: @Michael  i understand that but i dont know how to see the assembly code !

Comment: Ok, I don't know if there is a tag for that, but [tag:pep8] isn't it (though it has been used that way in the past)

Comment: If you managed to write it in java, you already know the logic. It should be a simple matter to rewrite in pep8, instead of trying to get java bytecode and somehow translate that.

Comment: @Jester   yes,  but the  only problem is that i dont know how to handle binary tree in assembly (googling  dont give me some good stuff !!!)

Comment: If you understand what a binary tree is, what is your problem? Try to ask a specific question.

Comment: I suppose you have read _Computer Systems_ by Stanley Warford? There's sample code for a linked list in section 6.5. Your binary tree is not so different; there are a few more fields in the node structure, and you need recursion (section 2.4) to traverse the tree. Like Jester said, you worked out the algorithm in Java, it should not be too hard to put all the pieces together. As for your second question, porting assembly from one processor architecture to another is harder than writing assembly from scratch; this was the main reason why K&R developed the C programming language, or so I'm told.